# JSON view of an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, web-services, activerecord, models

I want to build a RESTful WebService that's using JSON for externalizing resources. The problem that I'm currently facing is how to construct a stripped-off version of my models so that I could offer clients a simplified interface without unneeded information.
The best aproach I could come up with is defining a method for every model that I'm interested in that builds this simplified facade object.
Is there a better design pattern for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try  [rabl](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl) or [jbuilder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest checking out https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers